# Ошибка обновлений Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

Подскажите пожалуйста как пофиксить данную ошибку.Надпись ошибка обновления Windows и откат настроек висит часа 2 уже и ничего не сделать,ничего не помогает крома как откатиться к точке восстановления,каждый раз откатываться т

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сразу после отката к точке восстановления - загрузитесь с установочного диска в режиме восстановления, и там в командной строке выполните:

```
DISM /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions
```

Взято с http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2009/10/15/getting-out-of-a-no-boot-situation-after-installing-updates-on-windows-7-2008r2.aspx

P.S. да, не слишком в тему на SO, но это решает очень распространенную ошибку при обновлениях, и потенциально спасает день-два работы системному администратору.